# How do I install Ubuntu without nouveau?

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, system-installation, nouveau

I can't install Ubuntu 16.04 because Nouveau doesn't support my GPU.
I've tried adding nouveau.modeset=0 and nomodeset to my install parameters but without succes. I interrupt the boot with esc to add advanced option nomodeset and then I press enter to start installation with this parameter. The screen loads for 5 seconds (Purple 16.04 loading) and then throws a nouveau error for a split second followed by my monitor giving a "signal out of range" error.

Titan XP
Intel 6900K
500GB SSD
UEFi

How can this be resolved?
Adam

Comment: You need `nomodeset` until you install the proprietary Nvidia drivers only. It has nothing to do with `nouveau` being there or not.

Comment: As I said in my post, I've tried nomodeset but it does still not start the installation.

Comment: If so please edit edit your question and describe exactly what happens with `nomodeset` and while at that also add your hardware specs and, if applicable, whether your attempting an EFI or Legacy installation.

Comment: I can boot in failsafe extreme mode on Debian 9, but also not on the other modes.